# No file was submitted when try to send generated PDF file from React Js to Django-Rest Post request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, jspdf, html2canvas

Trying to generate pdf file in react js and then sending it to the django rest backend.

I have successfully created the pdf file using jsPDF and html2canvas, but now unable to send to the rest api, whenever I submit it gives me response "No file was submitted".I have checked django-rest api's and its working fine, the pdf is not going to the rest api's.Here's my below code:

```
genPDF=(evt)=>{
    evt.preventDefault();
   html2canvas(document.getElementById("pdfid")).then(canvas=>{
       let img=canvas.toDataURL('img/png');
       let doc=new JsPDF();
       doc.addImage(img,'JPEG',30,30);
       //doc.save('test.pdf');
       let file=doc;
       const formdata=new FormData();
       formdata.append("file",file);
       this.postpdf(formdata)
   });

};

postpdf=(payload)=>{

    fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/chauffeur/pdf_upload/`,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(payload),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
    ).then(response => response.json()).catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
};
```

**Request Headers**

```
       Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----                       
       WebKitFormBoundaryEueEwtpzbquHU6Tb
       Origin: http://localhost:3000
       Referer: http://localhost:3000/contractinvoice
       User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
       Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36
```

**Response Headers**

```
       Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
       Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
       Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
       Content-Length: 76
       Content-Type: application/json
       Date: Wed, 10 Apr 2019 05:44:49 GMT
       Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.5.2
       Vary: Accept, Cookie, Origin
       X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

I think I am sending the file in a wrong but can't sort it what's the problem,need for suggestions.Thanks

Comment: Hey, I am in a similar situation and I haven't figured out a solution yet. Was wondering if you did? Please let me know

Answer (score 1):

You have error here:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

If you want to send file, you should use **multipart/form-data**

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to convert payload to JSON.stringify()... payload is not json...
try this...

```
postpdf=(payload)=>{

    fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/chauffeur/pdf_upload/`,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            body: payload,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        }
    ).then(response => response.json()).catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
};
```

Comment: added in my question kindly check.